# Large PHP arrays or MySQL temporary memory tables?

Tags: php, mysql, key-value

How would you temporarily store several thousands of `key => value` or `key => array` pairs within a single process. Lookups on `key` will be done continuously within the process, and the data is discarded when the process ends.

Should i use arrays? temporary MySQL tables? Or something in between?

Comment: PHP is usually used for writing web pages - but something which accumulates several thousand key/values does not sound like a web page. Understanding how data is added and the pattern of dereferencing would be a pre-requisite to even hazarding a guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how many several thousands mean and how big the array gets in the memory. If you can handle it in PHP, you should do it, because the usage of mysql creates a little overhead here.

But if you are on a shared host, or you have limited `memory_limit` in the php.ini and can't increase it you can use a temporary table in MySQL.

Also you can use some simple and fast key value storage like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/), they can also work in Memory only, and have a real fast lookup of keys (Redis promises [Time Complexity of O(1)](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/GetCommand))

Comment: What is the down vote for? I would appreciate a comment here, so I know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Several thousand?! You mean it could take up several KILObytes?!

Are you sure this is going to be an issue? Before optimizing, write the code the simplest, straightforward way, and check later what really needs optimalization. Also, only having the benchmark and the full code will you be able to decide on the proper way of caching. Everything else is a waste of time and the root of all evil...

Answer (score 2):

[Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is a popular way of caching data.

If you're only running that one process and don't need to worry about concurrent access, I would do it inside php. If you have multiple processes I would use some established solution so you don't have to worry about the details.

Comment: I only need to store the data within a single process. The data is generated there, and it dies there. I don't see how memcached would help with that?

Comment: Then I would argue against mysql, just keep the data inside php

Comment: memcached should be faster than mysql for this specific type of problem

Comment: But memcache is a CACHE, that means data gets lost, when the cache is full.

Comment: I don't know a lot of memcached, but I believe it can be configured to keep the date until it's deleted by the user or by the application. But you can also use Redis, what is similar to memcached, and redis definitely don't remove data until the user or the app removes the data, and it's really fast

Comment: I had this dilemma once when I was on an "optimising" rampage of our PHP code and went to use Memcache to store a ~70K array that was changing often. Turned out that Memcache also has its overhead (mainly when storing the data, and some on retrieval) and we were better off managing that array in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your application and your hardware. My bet, is to let databases do (especially MySQL) just Databases' work. I mean, not to much work than store and retrieve data. Other DBMS may be real efficient (Informix, for example) but sadly, MySQL is not.
Temporary tables may be more efficient than PHP arrays, but you increase the number of connections tu the DB.

Scalability is an issue too. Doing it in PHP is better in that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of difficult to give a straight answer if we don't get the complete picture.
It depens where you source data is.

- If your data is in the database, you better keep it there and manipulate it there and just get the items you need. Use temp tables if necessarily
- If you data is already in PHP you probably better keep in there. Although handling data in PHP is quite intensive

Answer (score 0):

- If the data lookup will be done with only few queries do it with mysql temporary table.
- If there will be many data lookups its almost always best to store it in php side. (connection overhead)